# What are three different techniques to convolve a signal

Tags: convolution

I have studied convolution in time domain and frequency domain. But doesn't know the 3rd method and technique

Comment: The question is a bit unclear, but there are different ways of applying the convolution and there is definitely more than 3. Direct in time domain, in frequency domain, overlap-add, overlap-save, zero-delay, etc. It all depends how you want to group them.